# Refresh div with data sent by controller in session every 2 seconds, laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

How to refresh laravel session variable sent by controller, my controller is:

```
public function ordert()
{   
    $tables = Table::all();
    return view('ordert.ordert',['tables'=>$tables]);
}
```

and I am showing this data in view as :

```
 <tbody>
   @foreach($tables as $table)
    <tr id=""> 
      <td style="text-align: center;">
         <button class="btn" >{{$table->table_no}} </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

i want to refresh this data (tables) every 2 seconds, how can i do that ?

Comment: Use javascript interval to run ajax call every 2 mins, or CRON on PHP side.

Comment: but i have not called data through ajax, can i refresh laravel session variable?

Comment: AFAIK you need to implement your session refreshing mechanism, like if you keep login you facebook for a month without opening it in your browser, but if you open it after a quarter it will present you with login screen.